# equals and hashCode of these entities (Spring MVC + Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, equals, hashcode

Someone can please suggest me how I can do equals and hashCode methods of these entities?

This is a many-to-many relationship between a Gara (Contest) and Agenzia (Agency):
One contest has many Agency, one Agency can be in more Contest.

I tried some implementations but or I get Stackoverflow error, or,
when I'm updating a Gara (Contest), I can't update the set of Agenzie (Agencies) because i get this error:

> org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: a different object with
>   the same identifier value was already associated with the session:
>   [com.myApp.model.GaraAgenzia#com.mmyApp.model.GaraAgenziaId@49f];
>   nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a
>   different object with the same identifier value was already associated
>   with the session:
>   [com.myApp.model.GaraAgenzia#com.myApp.model.GaraAgenziaId@49f]

when i try to do an update.

thanks

**Gare.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gare")
public class Gara extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6395640401966812691L;


    /*
     * inizializzo logger
     */
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Gara.class);


    /*
     * molti a molti gara-agenzia
     * 
     * EAGER altrimenti da errore:  could not initialize proxy - no Session
     */
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.gara", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true) 
    private Set<GaraAgenzia> garaAgenzie = new HashSet<GaraAgenzia>(0); 



    /*
     * molti a molti gara-servizi
     * 
     * EAGER altrimenti da errore:  could not initialize proxy - no Session
     */
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.gara", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<GaraServizio> garaServizi = new HashSet<GaraServizio>(0);                


    /*
     *  
     * colonna TITOLO
     * 
     */
   @NotNull(message = "Il campo TITOLO è obbligatorio")                     
   @NotEmpty(message = "Il campo TITOLO è obbligatorio")                    
   @Size(min = 0, max = 255, message = "Lunghezza massima campo TITOLO: 255 caratteri")     
   @Column(name = "TITOLO", length = 255)    
   private String titolo;





    /*
     *  
     * colonna OBIETTIVO
     * 
     */
    @NotNull(message = "Il campo OBIETTIVO è obbligatorio")                     
    @Min(value = 1, message = "Il campo OBIETTIVO deve essere maggiore di ZERO")    
    @Column(name = "OBIETTIVO")    
    private int obiettivo = 0;


    /*
     *  
     * colonna BONUS
     * 
     */
    @NotNull(message = "Il campo BONUS è obbligatorio")                     
    @Min(value = 1, message = "Il campo BONUS deve essere maggiore di UNO")     
    @Column(name = "BONUS")    
    private float bonus = 0f;

     @Column(name = "data_iniziale", nullable = false)      
     private Date dataIniziale;

     @Column(name = "data_finale", nullable = false)    
     private Date dataFinale;


    public Set<GaraAgenzia> getGaraAgenzie() {
        return garaAgenzie;
    }

    public void setGaraAgenzie(Set<GaraAgenzia> garaAgenzie) {
        this.garaAgenzie.clear();
        this.garaAgenzie = garaAgenzie;
    }

    public Set<GaraServizio> getGaraServizi() {
        return garaServizi;
    }

    public void setGaraServizi(Set<GaraServizio> garaServizi) {
        this.garaServizi.clear();
        this.garaServizi = garaServizi;
    }

        public void GaraServizio(GaraServizio gara_servizio) {
            garaServizi.add(gara_servizio);
            gara_servizio.setGara(this);
        }

        public void removeGaraServizio(GaraServizio gara_servizio) {
            garaServizi.remove(gara_servizio);
            gara_servizio.setGara(null);
        }   

        public void GaraAgenzia(GaraAgenzia gara_agenzia) {
            garaAgenzie.add(gara_agenzia);
            gara_agenzia.setGara(this);
        }

        public void removeGaraAgenzia(GaraAgenzia gara_agenzia) {
            garaAgenzie.remove(gara_agenzia);
            gara_agenzia.setGara(null);
        }   







    public String getTitolo() {
        return titolo;
    }

    public void setTitolo(String titolo) {
        this.titolo = titolo;
    }

    public int getObiettivo() {
        return obiettivo;
    }

    public void setObiettivo(int obiettivo) {
        this.obiettivo = obiettivo;
    }

    public float getBonus() {
        return bonus;
    }

    public void setBonus(float bonus) {
        this.bonus = bonus;
    }

    public Date getDataIniziale() {
        return dataIniziale;
    }

    public void setDataIniziale(Date dataIniziale) {
        this.dataIniziale = dataIniziale;
    }

    public Date getDataFinale() {
        return dataFinale;
    }

    public void setDataFinale(Date dataFinale) {
        this.dataFinale = dataFinale;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Gara [garaAgenzie=" + garaAgenzie + ", garaServizi="
                + garaServizi + ", titolo=" + titolo + ", obiettivo="
                + obiettivo + ", bonus=" + bonus + ", dataIniziale="
                + dataIniziale + ", dataFinale=" + dataFinale + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + Float.floatToIntBits(bonus);
        result = prime * result
                + ((dataFinale == null) ? 0 : dataFinale.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((dataIniziale == null) ? 0 : dataIniziale.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + obiettivo;
        result = prime * result + ((titolo == null) ? 0 : titolo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Gara other = (Gara) obj;
        if (Float.floatToIntBits(bonus) != Float.floatToIntBits(other.bonus))
            return false;
        if (dataFinale == null) {
            if (other.dataFinale != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dataFinale.equals(other.dataFinale))
            return false;
        if (dataIniziale == null) {
            if (other.dataIniziale != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dataIniziale.equals(other.dataIniziale))
            return false;
        if (obiettivo != other.obiettivo)
            return false;
        if (titolo == null) {
            if (other.titolo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!titolo.equals(other.titolo))
            return false;
        return true;
    }   


}
```

**GaraAgenzia.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gare_agenzie")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.gara", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "gara_id")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.agenzia", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "agenzia_id")) })

public class GaraAgenzia implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3865586469933888797L;


    /*
     * inizializzo logger
     */
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GaraAgenzia.class);

    /*
     *  
     * numero contratti:
     * 
     * 
     */                         
    private int numeroContratti = 0; 

    private GaraAgenziaId pk = new GaraAgenziaId();

    @EmbeddedId
    public GaraAgenziaId getPk() {
          return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(GaraAgenziaId pk) {
          this.pk = pk;
    }   

    @Transient
    public Gara getGara() {
        return getPk().getGara();
    }

    public void setGara(Gara gara) {
        getPk().setGara(gara);
    }

    @Transient
    public Agenzia getAgenzia() {
        return getPk().getAgenzia();
    }

    public void setAgenzia(Agenzia agenzia) {
        getPk().setAgenzia(agenzia);
    }


    @Column(name = "numero_contratti")
    public int getNumeroContratti() {
        return numeroContratti;
    }

    public void setNumeroContratti(int numeroContratti) {
        this.numeroContratti = numeroContratti;
    }

      public boolean equals(Object other) {
            if (this == other) return true;
            if ( !(other instanceof GaraAgenzia) ) return false;

            final GaraAgenzia gara_agenzia = (GaraAgenzia) other;

            if ( !gara_agenzia.getGara().equals( getGara() ) ) return false;
            if ( !gara_agenzia.getAgenzia().equals( getAgenzia() ) ) return false;

            return true;
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            int result;
            result = getGara().hashCode();
            result = 29 * result + getAgenzia().hashCode();
            return result;
        }   
}
```

**GaraAgenziaId.java:**

```
@Embeddable 
public class GaraAgenziaId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4934033367128755763L;


    /*
     * inizializzo logger
     */
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GaraAgenziaId.class);

    private Gara gara;

    private Agenzia agenzia;

    @ManyToOne
    public Gara getGara() {
        return gara;
    }

    public void setGara(Gara gara) {
        this.gara = gara;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Agenzia getAgenzia() {
        return agenzia;
    }

    public void setAgenzia(Agenzia agenzia) {
        this.agenzia = agenzia;
    }

    /*
     * override del metodo di uguaglianza
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null)
            return false;

        if (o instanceof GaraAgenzia) {
            final GaraAgenzia other = (GaraAgenzia) o;
            return (Objects.equal(getGara().getId(), other.getGara().getId())) && (Objects.equal(getAgenzia().getId(), other.getAgenzia().getId()));
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*
     * override del metodo creazione hashcode
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getGara().getId(), getAgenzia().getId());
    }


    /*
      public boolean equals(Object other) {
            if (this == other) return true;
            if ( !(other instanceof GaraAgenziaId) ) return false;

            final GaraAgenziaId gara_agenzia = (GaraAgenziaId) other;

            if ( !gara_agenzia.getGara().equals( getGara() ) ) return false;
            if ( !gara_agenzia.getAgenzia().equals( getAgenzia() ) ) return false;

            return true;
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            int result;
            result = getGara().hashCode();
            result = 29 * result + getAgenzia().hashCode();
            return result;
        }

    */

    /*
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        GaraAgenziaId other = (GaraAgenziaId) obj;
        if (gara == null) {
            if (other.gara != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!gara.equals(other.gara))
            return false;
        if (agenzia == null) {
            if (other.agenzia != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!agenzia.equals(other.agenzia))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    */  
}
```

**Edit 1:**
If i clear the set of Agencies (and Services) before 
set again it:

```
    garaToUpdate.getGaraAgenzie().clear();
    garaToUpdate.getGaraServizi().clear();

    getCurrentSession().flush();

    garaToUpdate.setGaraAgenzie(gara.getGaraAgenzie());
    garaToUpdate.setGaraServizi(gara.getGaraServizi());

    getCurrentSession().update(garaToUpdate);
```

i get this error:

> A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer
>   referenced by the owning entity instance:

**Edit 2:**
As suggested by @JamesB, i added the toString method to GaraAgenzia and GaraAgenziaId. Here the result BEFORE update the Gara record:

this is the record taken from db just before update it

> INFO : com.machinet.model.GaraAgenziaId - garaToUpdate.GaraAgenzie
>   (before update): [GaraAgenzia [numeroContratti=0, pk=GaraAgenziaId
>   [Gara=Gara [titolo=gara title, obiettivo=999, bonus=100.00,
>   dataIniziale=2014-07-31, dataFinale=2014-07-31], agenzia=Agenzia(id=1,
>   nome='Agency 1 ltd', ragione sociale=Agency 1 ltd srl)]]]

this is the edited record that will be set in db:

> INFO : com.machinet.model.GaraAgenziaId - editedGara.GaraAgenzie
>   (before update): [GaraAgenzia [numeroContratti=0, pk=GaraAgenziaId
>   [Gara=Gara [titolo=gara title, obiettivo=999, bonus=100.00,
>   dataIniziale=2014-07-31, dataFinale=2014-07-31], agenzia=Agenzia(id=1,
>   nome='Agency 1 ltd', ragione sociale=Agency 1 ltd srl]]]

Comment: Have you debugged the contents of Gare#garaAgenzie prior to saving the update?

Comment: I have the set of GareAgenzia assigned when i added the Gara to Db:  each record has "numeroContatti" (an additional field) and "pk" (which is the id entity)

Comment: Have you checked the IDs of each? By ID, I mean the embedded one.

Comment: the id from db are the same, but the id between parenthesis (i think is generated by compiler) are different

Comment: If the IDs from the database are the same, then you have the same entity within a Set which will not be allowed, hence the DuplicateKeyException.

Comment: I think it would be useful to override toString on the GaraAgenzia class and then post the debugger output of the Set just before you attempt to save.

Comment: yes.. it's my problem... i have a webflow with a form with checkboxes where i can edit a Gara (Contest): i can add/remove Servizi (Services) and Agenzie (agencies). So, i want to remove the services (or agencies) that have been unchecked in the form and add services/agencies that are checked. If a service (or agency) was already in the set before edit the contest i get DuplicateKeyException.

Comment: i added the toString result to the question. Thank you very much @JamesB for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These seem to work well. I post hoping someone will find it useful:

**GaraAgenzia class:**

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this== o) return true;
        if (o ==null|| getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        GaraAgenzia that = (GaraAgenzia) o;

        if (getPk() !=null?!getPk().equals(that.getPk()) : that.getPk() !=null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return (getPk() !=null? getPk().hashCode() : 0);
    }
```

**GaraAgenziaId class:**

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this== o) return true;
    if (o ==null|| getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    GaraAgenziaId that = (GaraAgenziaId) o;

    if (gara !=null?!gara.equals(that.gara) : that.gara !=null) return false;
    if (agenzia !=null?!agenzia.equals(that.agenzia) : that.agenzia !=null)
        return false;

    return true;
}

public int hashCode() {
    int result;
    result = (agenzia !=null? agenzia.hashCode() : 0);
    result =31* result + (gara !=null? gara.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Don't know if it's intended, but `equals` of `GaraAgenzia` will return `true` if both `this.pk` and `that.pk` are `null`.  
Vlad Mihalcea recommends doing a simpler `return id != null && this.id.equals(that.id);`
The `hashcode` also must return a constant value as per its contract (also recommended by hibernate docs),
so return a constant number or hash some properties that never change.
Mihalcea's blog: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/  
Also, see end of `Implementing equals() and hashCode()` in hibernate docs.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an exactly answer, but may help someone in a similar problem. I made a abstract class that is extended by all the entities. This way I don't need to implement these methods in all entities.

```
    public abstract class GenericEntity implements Serializable{

    protected static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    abstract public Serializable getId();

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return (getId() == null) ? System.identityHashCode(this) : getId().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        if (org.hibernate.Hibernate.getClass(this) != org.hibernate.Hibernate.getClass(obj))
            return false;
        GenericEntity other = (GenericEntity) obj;
        if (getId() == null || other.getId() == null)
            return false;
        return getId().equals(other.getId());
    }

}
```

I think in your case you could put it in your BaseEntity.